# I accidentally edited a question that is not mine, how can I delete it?

Tags: support, editing

I accidentally, thinking it is my question, wanted to update with how the info was going on. I was meanwhile looking at very similar questions to see if I can find any help or update there, this is why the accident happened.

How can I undo my edit proposal?

Comment: https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/665513
This is it

Comment: If not undo-able, thank you all for linking this while refusing the proposal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought you should be able to withdraw edit suggestions [but apparently not.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125730/undo-edit-suggestion)

I have rejected the edit citing this question.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can relax after the initial panic.

Comment: No worries, worst case would have been your edit being rejected as "an attempt to reply" or "conflicts with authors intent". Even if it had been accepted we could have rolled it back once you let us know it was an incorrect edit. No harm done.